# Show that if $\,u \in W^{1,p}\left(I\right) \bigcap C_c\left(I\right)$, then $\,u \in W_{0}^{1,p}\left(I\right)$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, convolution, weak-derivatives

I want to show the following statement ($1 \leq p < \infty$), for an open interval $I$:

> If $u \in W^{1,p}\left(I\right) \bigcap C_c\left(I\right)$ then $u  \in W_{0}^{1,p}\left(I\right) $.

$W^{1,p}\left(I\right) $ is the Sobolev Space, i.e. the space consisting of the functions that are in $L^p\left(I\right)$ with one (weak) derivative in $L^p\left(I\right)$ and $1 \leq p < \infty$ . $W_{0}^{1,p}\left(I\right) $ is the closure of $C_c^1\left(I\right)$ in $W^{1,p}\left(I\right) $. $C_c\left(I\right)$ is the set of the compactly supported functions defined on the interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$.

The norm for  an element $u \in W^{1,p}\left(I\right)$ is $\left\|u\right\|=\left\|u\right\|_p + \|u'\|_p$.

So this is equivalent to show that for every u in $ W^{1,p}\left(I\right) \bigcap C_c\left(I\right)$ there is a sequence $\left\lbrace u_n\right\rbrace_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $C^1_{c}\left(I\right)$ such that $\left\lbrace u_n\right\rbrace \to u$ in the norm $\left\|\cdot\right\|$.

I have considered using mollifiers, I have already shown that if $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$, then $\left\lbrace\rho_n*f\right\rbrace\to f $ in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ for a sequence $\left\lbrace\rho_n\right\rbrace$ of mollifiers. I do not know how to adapt this result for interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $I$ is supposed to be an open interval? Extend $f$ to all of $\mathbb{R}$ by setting $f(x) = 0$ for $x\notin I$. Then $\rho_n \ast f \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$, and $\operatorname{supp} (\rho_n \ast f) \subset I$ whenever the support of $\rho_n$ is small enough. Since $\rho_n \ast f$ vanishes identically outside $I$ - and hence the derivatives too - we have $\lVert f - \rho_n \ast f\rVert_{W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R})} = \lVert f - \rho_n \ast f\rVert_{W^{1,p}(I)}$ for these $n$.

Comment: Yes, $I$ is an open interval.

Comment: @DanielFischer For the sake of curiosity, does the proof also work for open sets in $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Yes, it does. The reason for my question was that if the interval $I$ is not open, then the assertion doesn't hold if $u \in C_c((a,b])$ doesn't imply $u(b) = 0$ - which is the case if $C_c(I) = \{ f \in C(I) : \operatorname{supp} f \text{ is compact}\}$ - and the proof is  more complicated if $C_c(I) = \{ f \in C_c(\mathbb{R} : \operatorname{supp} f \subseteq I\}$. When we have an open set, $u \in C_c(\Omega)$ vanishes in a uniform neighbourhood of the boundary, and the same argument works, all we need is that $\operatorname{supp}\rho_n +\operatorname{supp}u \subset \Omega$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Okay, thanks. Anyway I am working with Sobolev Spaces over open domains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following two theorems (see *Partial Differential Equations* (chapter 5) by Evans) can answer your question:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am using a different aproximation without using Trace Theorem, and I need the result asked for to show Theorem 2 in your post. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Then you can read the proof of the Trace Theorem in Evans's book.

Comment: I have red the proof but it is nowhere shown the result asked.

Comment: By the way,  I understand another approach to conclude the result is: As $u \in W^{1,p}(U) \cap C(\overline{U})$ and $u=0$ on $\partial U$ then, by **Theorem $2$** we have $u \in W_0^{1,p}(U)$. But it is important to note that by using the approach given by  Daniel Fischer one does not need to have as hypotesis that $U$ is of class $C^1$. Right?

Comment: In your question, $I$ is an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$, which is of class $C^1$.

Comment: True, I just wanted to mention the problem for $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Yes. That would be an interesting question.