# If $f \in L^p(\Omega)$, then $(\rho_n *f) \to f $ in $L^p(\Omega)$, for a sequence $(\rho_n)$ of mollifiers.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convolution, regularization

I am reading Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations, by Haim Brezis. There it is shown that:

> If we have $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then $(\rho_n *f) \to f $ in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$, for a sequence $(\rho_n)$ of mollifiers.  **(*)**

I would like to know if this result still holds for an open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and also how to prove it, i.e:

> $f \in L^p(\Omega)$, then $(\rho_n *f) \to f $ in $L^p(\Omega)$, for a sequence $(\rho_n)$ of mollifiers and any open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

Note: Brezis relies on the density of $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to show the result stated here for $\mathbb{R}^n$ **(*)**, and **then** shows this result that, indeed,  $C_c(\Omega)$ is dense in $L^p(\Omega)$, for any open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: But on Brezis there is this proof, you do not understand?

Comment: There is no proof in Brezis for a general open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. It is only stated (and proven) for $\mathbb{R^n}$

Comment: See well, Corollary 4.23.

Comment: It is conceivable that you need to assume something about the boundary of $\Omega$.

Comment: @JohnMartin No, Corolary 4.23 shows that $C_c(\Omega)$ is dense in $L^p(\Omega)$, for any open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the result you ask about cannot be true because if $f\in L^p(\Omega)$ then $\rho*f(x)$ is *undefined* for $x$ near the boundary (because the definition involves $f(x-t)$ where $x-t\notin\Omega$).

Given $f\in L^p(\Omega)$ you can make sense of $\rho*f$ by regarding $f$ as defined on all of $\Bbb R^n$ and vanishing off $\Omega$. But then you're not really talking about $L^p(\Omega)$, and in any case $\rho*f$ is not supported in $\Omega$.

Of course there's no problem using convolutions to show that $C_c(\Omega)$ is dense in $L^p(\Omega)$. First choose $g\in L^p(\Omega)$ so that $||f-g||_p<\epsilon$ and such that $g$ vanishes outside some compact set $K\subset\Omega$; now if the support of $\rho$ is small enough you will have $\rho*g\in C_c(\Omega)$.

Comment: I need the resultados to show this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1744862/if-u-in-w1-pi-cap-c-ci-then-u-in-w-01-pi